# doesn't compile if included boost/thread in linux Ubuntu:)10.10

Tags: c++, linux, boost, compiler-errors

I work in eclipse under linux UBUNTU:) 10.10, installed the boost-dev packages 1.40 using the Synaptic pkg manager. I am new to linux and this boost pkg. I try to create a new project, and write:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
}
```

I did not include anything or write anything like pthread anywhere.
when trying to build, it says:

```
/usr/include/boost/config/requires_threads.hpp:47: error: #error "Compiler threading support is not turned on. Please set the correct command line options for threading: -pthread (Linux), -pthreads (Solaris) or -mthreads (Mingw32)"
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from ../main.cpp:8:
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/platform.hpp:67: error: #error "Sorry, no boost threads are available for this platform."
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from ../main.cpp:8:
/usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:19: error: #error "Boost threads unavailable on this platform"
```

and so on, a lot of more errors related to boost.
I tried to add `-pthread`, `-pthreads`, `-lpthread` to where I thought I could, but did not solve the problem.
I forgot to mention, that I try to build the project in eclipse, I don't work in the command line, but I also tried g++ -pthread main.cpp and it gives the exact same error. 
Please give detailed or stepbystep solution, because some things you answer here are simply chinese to me. I just want to get a simple thing running and don't even understand the problem. Don't even understand that error message, what does it want me to do.
basically what I did: install eclipse, write the above things in a new project, install libboost 1.4 using sinaptic pkg manager, and restarted everything and tried to compile. I got the error. Don't see what's happening, or what am I missing. (I have libc-dev)
Stack is really flowing over now. need some sleep to cool down. thank you guys for help!

Comment: Whoa, that's the first time i've heard Linux called Linux 10.10.
Ubuntu must have had some impact, no doubt. :-)

Comment: sorry, I am new to all this linux and ubuntu stuff, but yes, that was a mistake:) funny though

Comment: Show your compile command line in full in your question.  Boost threads just wrap the underlying OS threads so by including boost/thread.hpp you are requesting pthreads.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I try to build the project in eclipse, I don't work in the command line, but I also tried g++ -pthread main.cpp and it gives the exact same error. 
Please give detailed or stepbystep solution, because some things you answer here are simply chinese to me. I just want to get a simple thing running and don't even understand the problem. Don't even understand that error message, what does it want me to do.basically what I did: install eclipse,write the above things in a newproject,install libboost1.4using sinapticpkgmanager,restart everything and compile. whats wrong?

Answer (score 11):

The issue is a well known one from such an old version of boost. You are compiling with gcc/g++ 4.7, where the reference to pthreads have changed to GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS, so boost is unable to find pthreads and disable it.

So you have two options:

1) Upgrade boost_dev to last release (I think it's fixed in 1.50+).

2) Patch your boost include files (I've done this); just edit

*"your boost folder"/include/config/stdlib/libstdcpp3.hpp*

and change:

```
#ifdef __GLIBCXX__ // gcc 3.4 and greater:
#  if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAVE_GTHR_DEFAULT) \
        || defined(_GLIBCXX__PTHREADS)
      //
      // If the std lib has thread support turned on, then turn it on in Boost
      // as well.  We do this because some gcc-3.4 std lib headers define _REENTANT
      // while others do not... 
      //
#     define BOOST_HAS_THREADS
#  else
#     define BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS
#  endif
```

to add the new directive in the condition:

```
#ifdef __GLIBCXX__ // gcc 3.4 and greater:
#  if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAVE_GTHR_DEFAULT) \
        || defined(_GLIBCXX__PTHREADS) \
        || defined(_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS) // gcc 4.7 
      //
      // If the std lib has thread support turned on, then turn it on in Boost
      // as well.  We do this because some gcc-3.4 std lib headers define _REENTANT
      // while others do not...  
      //
#     define BOOST_HAS_THREADS
#  else
#     define BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS
#  endif
```

Bug description and fixes for linux and windows here:

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6165

Enjoy.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with `g++ test.cpp -pthread -lboost_thread`.

Comment: There must be something broken with your packages. Try reinstalling boost and g++.

Comment: Hmm. Tried that also...same error. should I install 10.04 now instead of 10.10?

Comment: I use 10.10 myself and I have no issues whatsoever. I have no idea what could be causing yours.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the boost thread libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-thread-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message say: pass `-pthread` to the compiler:

```
g++ -pthread yourfile.cpp
```

Also, for debian, make sure you have `libc-dev` installed.

Comment: Thanks,It tried this, but it gives exactly the same message-this time it writes it into the terminal of course. I was wondering, how could I run this in eclipse instead of the terminal. /usr/include/boost/config/requires_threads.hpp:47: error: #error "Compiler threading support is not turned on. Please set the correct command line options for threading: -pthread (Linux), -pthreads (Solaris) or -mthreads (Mingw32)"

Comment: I have libc-dev. any other tips?