# installation & compilation boost on Manjaro

Tags: c++, installation, boost, compilation, manjaro

I installed boost using `pacman -S boost boost-libs`.
When I try to compile a program that uses `boost::thread`, and I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc3AkelG.o: warning: relocation against `_ZTVN5boost6detail16thread_data_baseE' in read-only section `.text._ZN5boost6detail16thread_data_baseC2Ev[_ZN5boost6detail16thread_data_baseC5Ev]'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: What version of GCC are you using?

Comment: Check out this question about how to [configure your compiler to output errors in english](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869309/selecting-message-language-in-gcc-and-g). This would probably get you better answers faster, as more people will be able to understand the error.

Comment: I'm using gcc 11.1.0 and thanks for the advice @He3lixxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the answer in an [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389853/doesnt-compile-if-included-boost-thread-in-linux-ubuntu10-10).

I had to compile using -pthread -lboost_thread.

thanks for your answer.